# how do I rewrite a URL in nginx to an updated location?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have the following URLs:

```
1) http://example.com/downloads/
2) http://example.com/downloads/widgets
3) http://example.com/downloads/gadgets
```

These URLs need to be <s>redirected</s> rewritten to the following:

```
1) http://example.com/products/
2 & 3 & etc) http://example.com/products/thingies
```

I'm currently trying the following nginx code:

```
location ~* ^/downloads/ {
    rewrite ^/downloads/$ /products break;
    rewrite ^/downloads/(.*)$ /products/thingies break;
}
```

It's *almost* working, however my site's document root is `/var/www/example.com/public`. So after processing the rewrite rules, nginx tries to literally serve `/var/www/example.com/public/products/`, whereas I *want* it to just rewrite to `http://example.com/products/` (which then proxies to PHP and so on).

Where am I failing? Is there a different, better way to accomplish this?

Thank you for any help.

### -- UPDATE --

I got it to work by using the following rules:

rewrite ^/downloads/?$ $scheme://$host/tools last;

```
location ~* ^/downloads/ {
    rewrite ^/downloads/?$ $scheme://$host/products last; 
    rewrite ^/downloads/(.*)$ $scheme://$host/products/thingies last;
}
```

IS this the proper way of doing it in nginx? I haven't seen this rewrite rule format anywhere while researching this. It somehow seems odd.

Comment: You should use `last` instead of `break`.

Comment: Do you need redirect (send user browser to new url) or rewrite (act as if user required `/products/` instead of `/downloads/`)?

Comment: I need to rewrite (updated the question - thank you for catching that). 
As for using "last" - won't that restart rule processing and cause a redirect loop? as per nginx docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: you're right, "last" did the trick, along with $scheme://$host. I'm not sure this is the right way of doing it though - is there a more correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update redirects, not rewrites.

Here is how I would do:

```
location /downloads/ {
    rewrite ^ /products/thingies;
}

location = /downloads/ {
    rewrite ^ /products/;
}

# uncomment if you need '/downloads' (without trailing slash) act as '/downloads/'
#location = /downloads {
#    rewrite ^ /products/;
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax appears to be:

```
location ~* ^/downloads/ {
    rewrite ^/downloads/?$ /products permanent; 
    rewrite ^/downloads/(.*)$ /products/thingies permanent;
}
```